# Merge CSV files in subfolders

Tags: powershell

I have found a script which does everything that I need, but it's only useful if you run it in a single folder. What I'd like is:

Script is located in c:/temp/. Upon running the script, it would go into each subfolder and execute. Each subfolder would then have a separate Final.csv.

Somebody mentioned just add -Recurse, but it doesn't complete the job as described. With -Recurse added, it goes into each subfolder and creates a Final.csv final in the root dir (C:/temp/) instead of creating a Final.csv in each subfolder.

```
$getFirstLine = $true

get-childItem *.csv | foreach {
    $filePath = $_

    $lines = Get-Content $filePath  
    $linesToWrite = switch($getFirstLine) {
           $true  {$lines}
           $false {$lines | Select -Skip 2}

    }

    $getFirstLine = $false
    Add-Content Final.csv $linesToWrite
    }
```

Comment: Like this you're not _merging_ csv files, but regardless of the headers, column order, delimiter character etc. you simply add lines of text together, undoubtably resulting in a non-functional csv file.. Also, what is the use of `switch($getFirstLine)` when variable `$getFirstLine` is not defined as being `$true` to start with?

Comment: @Theo Nah, "merge" isn't a uniquely defined operation. It could be a horizontal merge or a vertical merge, if you follow my meaning.

Comment: added the variable. It's actually creating a csv that I can work with... as I mentioned, it's doing everything correct, I'd just like to make it work in the subfolders. I don't mind changing the code completely as long as I achieve what I need here...

btw, this script copies the headers of the first two rows from the first file and then removes it from all others when merging the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain the csv files combined this way will leave you a valid 'Final.csv', you need to use `Group-Object` in order to create a combined file in each of the directories where the csv files to combine are found.

Suppose you have a folder with subfolders 'Folder1' and 'Folder2', both having csv files in them like these:

**first.csv**

```
Lorem,Ipsum,Dolor,Sic,Amet
data1-1,data1-2,data1-3,data1-4,data1-5
data2-1,data2-2,data2-3,data2-4,data2-5
```

**second.csv**

```
Lorem,Ipsum,Dolor,Sic,Amet
something,blah,whatever,very important,here's more..
```

Then this should do it for you:

```
$targetFileName = 'Final.csv'

# loop over the CSV files, but exclude the Final.csv file
# Group the files by their DirectoryNames
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.csv' -File -Recurse -Exclude $targetFileName | Group-Object DirectoryName | ForEach-Object {
    # reset the $getFirstLine variable for each group
    $getFirstLine = $true
    # create the target path for the combined csv inside this folder. 
    # ($_.Name is the name of the group, which is the Directory name of the files inside the group)
    $target = Join-Path -Path $_.Name -ChildPath $targetFileName
    foreach ($file in $_.Group) {
        if ($getFirstLine) {
            # copy the first CSV as a whole
            Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | Set-Content -Path $target
            $getFirstLine = $false
        }
        else {
            # add the content of the next file(s) without the header line
            Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Add-Content -Path $target
        }
    }
}
```

The end result is that each subfolder will have a new 'Final.csv' file containing

```
Lorem,Ipsum,Dolor,Sic,Amet
data1-1,data1-2,data1-3,data1-4,data1-5
data2-1,data2-2,data2-3,data2-4,data2-5
something,blah,whatever,very important,here's more..
```

<sup>Of course I'm just showing an example for one of the subfolders.. Other subfolders will contain different 'Final.csv' content</sup>

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks! I've marked it